# Узгодження дієслів з іменниками у множині

Tags: дієслова, conjugation

Чи є одна з наступних фраз некоректною, чи обидві форми дієслова "навчатися" у наступному реченні є граматично коректними?

- Чим більше людей навч**и**ться робити ... (суб’єкт дії - третя особа однини)
- Чим більше людей навч**а**ться робити ... (суб’єкт дії - третя особа множини)

Мені обидва варіанти здаються правильними, принаймні вживаними, але маю сумніви.

Comment: схоже, що 1-й варіант - скорочена версія _"Чим більша **кількість** людей навчиться"_..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Питання узгодження дієслів з іменниками, мабуть, варто розглядати в контексті узгодження присудка з підметом, при цьому останній не обов'язково має бути іменником. Принаймні, інформація, яку вдалося знайти, відображається саме так.

Стисло й доступно викладено у [«Як ми говоримо» Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/chyslovi-osoblyvosti-diyeslova-prysudka):

> **Числові особливості дієслова-присудка**
>
> **Дієслово-присудок звичайно узгоджується в числі з підметом речення**: ***якщо підмет стоїть в однині, то й дієслово-присудок
>   також виступає в однині*** («*Посадила стара мати три ясені в полі*».
>   — Т. Шевченко); ***а множина підмета зумовлює й множину
>   дієслова-присудка*** («*На чужину з України брати розійшлися*». — Т.
>   Шевченко).
>
> Проте бувають випадки, коли дієслово-присудок стоїть в іншому числі,
>   ніж підмет: «Був собі дід та баба» (казка). Здавалось би, що за
>   наявності в цьому реченні двох підметів — дід та баба —
>   дієслово-присудок слід було б поставити в множині, але **якщо
>   дієслово-присудок стоїть перед двома або кількома підметами, а перший
>   підмет стоїть в однині, то й дієслово стоятиме теж в однині**: *«Був
>   собі котик та півник»* (казка).
>
> **Дієслово-присудок виступає в однині також тоді, коли підмет має при собі додаток, що становить із підметом одну підметову групу речення й
>   пов’язується з ним прийменником *`з`***: «*Гарматний відгомін з першим
>   громом мішався раз у раз в одних розкатів жмут*» (М. Бажан).
>
> **Дієслово-присудок буде в однині й тоді, коли за підмет правлять збірні слова — *`більшість`*, *`меншість`*, `частина`, *`ряд`*,
>   `кілька`, `багато`, *`чимало`*, *`група`*, `низка`, *`решта`*,
>   *`половина`* та інші, поєднані з залежними від них іменниками (прикметниками) в родовому відмінку**: «*Більшість присутніх пристала
>   на цю пропозицію*»; «*Кілька відер води бухнуло на вогон*ь» (М.
>   Коцюбинський).
>
> **Якщо підмет складається з числівника *`два`*, `три`, *`чотири`* й іменника, а в реченні мовиться про спільну дію, дієслово-присудок слід
>   ставити в однині**: «*Летить чотири утиці*» (Б. Грінченко); «*На полу
>   лежало три чоловіки*» (Панас Мирний). **Якщо в реченні треба
>   підкреслити, що особи, які складають підмет із числівником, діють
>   кожна окремо, дієслово-присудок годиться ставити в множині**: «*Не
>   вертаються три брати, по світу блукають*» (Т. Шевченко).
>
> **Якщо підметом є складений числівник, де останнє слово — `один`, дієслово-присудок може стояти в однині в чоловічому роді або в
>   безособовій формі на *`-ло`*:** «*31 солдат вийшов з оточення*»,
>   «*Вийшло з оточення 31 солдат*». **Якщо перед таким підметом є
>   означення в множині (*`усі`*, *`наші`* й под.), присудок має форму
>   множини**: «*Усі двадцять один учасник конкурсу вийшли на змагання*».

Розлогіше, кому цікаво, - на ["Офіційному сайті української мови"](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/sintaksis_i_punktuacija/uzgodzhennja_prisudka_z_pidmetom/7-1-0-178)

Є ще стаття ["У якій формі вжити присудок?" Н.Я.Дзюбишиної](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine30-9.pdf), для тих, кому до вподоби науковий стиль викладу.