# "ЗнаходИться" чи "знаходЯться"?

Tags: число

Який із нижченаведених варіантів є правильним і чому?

- "Більше прикладів знаходЯться за посиланням http://www.example.com"
- "Більше прикладів знаходИться за посиланням http://www.example.com"

Comment: А що ви маєте на увазі: приклади розміщені на тому сайті, чи на тому сайті їх можна пошукати і знайти?

Comment: Приклади розміщені на сайті. Тобто в даному випадку "знаходяться" --- синонім слова "є".

Comment: Я б сказав, що якщо вважати *знаходиться* синонімом *є*, то тоді правильно саме знаходиться, бо *більше  прикладів* це однина, тобто тут ми говоримо не про приклади як набір.

Comment: Виходить щось подібне до "Ящик книг знаходИться на горищі"

Comment: [Тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/823/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%B7-%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96/1383#1383) - відповідь на подібне запитання з посиланнями на додаткові джерела до "Як ми говоримо" Антоненка-Давидовича.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> <sup>[Як ми говоримо](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/chyslovi-osoblyvosti-diyeslova-prysudka) • [Антоненка-Давидовича](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **Числові особливості дієслова-присудка**
>
> Дієслово-присудок звичайно узгоджується в числі з підметом речення: якщо підмет стоїть в однині, то й дієслово-присудок також виступає в однині («*Посадила* стара мати три ясені в полі». — Т. Шевченко); а множина підмета зумовлює й множину дієслова-присудка («На чужину з України брати *розійшлися*». — Т. Шевченко).
>
> Проте бувають випадки, коли дієслово-присудок стоїть в іншому числі, ніж підмет: «*Був* собі дід та баба» (казка). Здавалось би, що за наявності в цьому реченні двох підметів — *дід* та *баба* — дієслово-присудок слід було б поставити в множині, але якщо дієслово-присудок стоїть перед двома або кількома підметами, а перший підмет стоїть в однині, то й дієслово стоятиме теж в однині: «*Був* собі котик та півник» (казка).
>
> Дієслово-присудок виступає в однині також тоді, коли підмет має при собі додаток, що становить із підметом одну підметову групу речення й пов’язується з ним прийменником *з*: «Гарматний відгомін *з* першим громом *мішався* раз у раз в одних розкатів жмут» (М. Бажан).
>
> **Дієслово-присудок буде в однині й тоді, коли за підмет правлять збірні слова — *більшість, меншість, частина, ряд, кілька, багато* ([*більше*](http://sum.in.ua/s/biljshe) — вищий ступінь), *чимало, група, низка, решта, половина* та інші, поєднані з залежними від них іменниками (прикметниками) в родовому відмінку: «*Більшість* присутніх *пристала* на цю пропозицію»; «*Кілька* відер води *бухнуло* на вогонь» (М. Коцюбинський).**
>
> Якщо підмет складається з числівника *два, три, чотири* й іменника, а в реченні мовиться про спільну дію, дієслово-присудок слід ставити в однині: «*Летить чотири утиці*» (Б. Грінченко); «На полу *лежало три чоловіки*» (Панас Мирний). Якщо в реченні треба підкреслити, що особи, які складають підмет із числівником, діють кожна окремо, дієслово-присудок годиться ставити в множині: «Не *вертаються три брати*, по світу блукають» (Т. Шевченко).
>
> Якщо підметом є складений числівник, де останнє слово — *один*, дієслово-присудок може стояти в однині в чоловічому роді або в безособовій формі на *-ло*: «*31 солдат вийшов* з оточення», «*Вийшло* з оточення *31 солдат*». Якщо перед таким підметом є означення в множині (*усі, наші* й под.), присудок має форму множини: «*Усі двадцять один учасник* конкурсу *вийшли* на змагання».

---

> <sup>[З українського літературного слововживання](http://refos.in.ua/z-ukrayinsekogo-literaturnogo-slovovjivannya.html?page=6)</sup>
>   **Більшість**, -шості, *орудний* -шістю. При підметові, вираженому сполученням слова **більшість** з іменником або займенником у родовому відмінку однини чи множини, присудок ставиться у формі однини або множини.
>
> 1. Присудок у формі однини звичайно вживається:
>
>    - якщо при слові **більшість** немає керованого слова. *Більшість впевнена була, що в тому піску є золото* (М. Трублаїні); *Більшість, особливо молодь, вбачала в поїздці до Морниці веселу розвагу* (Ірина Вільде);
>    - якщо слово більшість має кероване слово в однині. *Переважна більшість народу підтримала цей захід*;
>    - **при безпосередньому сусідстві підмета й присудка (хоч кероване слово і вжите в множині). *Більшість молодих інтелігентних людей сидить по великих містах* (Леся Українка); *Більшість бійців зосередилась у залі другого поверху* (О. Гончар).**
> 2. Присудок у формі множини (в так званому узгодженні за змістом) звичайно вживається:
>
>    - якщо між підметом і присудком є інші члени речення, особливо дієприкметниковий зворот або означальне підрядне речення зі сполучниковими словами **який, котрий, що** при підметі. *Більшість делегатів при обговоренні питання, що стояло на порядку денному, підтримали доповідача*;
>    - якщо при слові **більшість** є кілька керованих слів у формі множини. *Більшість командирів і бійців полягли в цьому бою*;
>    - якщо при підметі є однорідні присудки. *Він бачив на фронті, що більшість людей гинуть тому, що не можуть використати місцевості для свого захисту і для наступу, не знають взаємодії родів військ, бояться ближніх боїв, авіації і танків* (Григорій Тютюнник);
>    - якщо підкреслюється активність і роздільність дії, здійснюваної виконавцями. *Більшість десятикласників готувались до екзаменів групками по двоє, по троє* (О. Донченко).

---

Додаткове

1. Дієслово **ся знаходити** (що тотожнє до **є**) можна не писати взагалі:
   *Більше прикладів за посиланням [адреса іменки]*.

---

**Висновок** [в цьому реченні]

*Більше прикладів* *знаход**и**ться* за посиланням [адреса іменки].

Comment: Будь Ваша ласка, додавайте TL;TR у разі таких великих цитувань. Поза тим, питання таке просте, нащо такий розпис? Посилання на джерело було б достатньо.

Comment: Плюсую розгорнуту відповідь. Тільки від того, що за такою простою конструкцією стоїть стільки правил та винятків, стає страшно :)

Comment: @Follower, "на посиланні" в мене викликало шок. Я, чесно кажучи, так і не зрозумів чому саме так правильно. Невже треба говорити "будинок знаходиться на адресі"?

Comment: @Follower, я підправив висновок

Comment: @Yola, так вкінці є висновок для цього конкретного випадку. Однак його, напевне, дійсно варто би було винести на початок, щоб відразу попадав на очі.

Comment: @Yola всі суттєві для даного випадку привила виділено жирним текстом